# Alternative ways to create Windows 11 widgets other than Adaptive Cards

Tags: xaml, winui-3, windows-11

I need to create custom widgets for Windows 11 .I have explored the option of using Adaptive Cards, but I am wondering if there are any other ways to create custom widgets for Windows 11.

Comment: AFAIK, Adaptive Cards is the recommend way to do this and it is mentioned in the Microsoft document. Otherwise, you need to write the xml on your own. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/widgets/widgets-create-a-template

Comment: I suggest you could start from the Docs:[Create Widgets for Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/tabs-vs-spaces/create-widgets-for-windows-11)